# Rails file upload w/ Paperclip and Polymorphic assocations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, paperclip

I am working on a rails app w/ locations, gyms, users, and images. All of these share images, so instead of doing image upload seperately per model, I liked the solution expressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279553/multiple-images-for-multiple-models-paperclip-rails) and wanted to recreate it.

Right now my models look like this

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  has_attached_file :image, style: { small: '64x64', medium: '100x100', large: '200x200' }
  validates_attachment :image, presence: true, content_type: { content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ }, 
                                                size: { in: 0..5.megabytes }
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  geocoded_by :county_name
  after_validation :geocode

  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures #added, not sure if needed or not
end
```

and here is the locations controller. My biggest concern with the controller is if I'm handling the nested params

```
class Admin::LocationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_admin!

  def new
    @location = Location.new
    @location.pictures.build
  end

  def create
    @location = Location.new(location_params)
    if @location.save
      flash[:success] = 'Location created!'
      redirect_to admin_location_path(@location)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  ...
  private
  def location_params
    params.require(:location).permit(:county_name, :description,
                                picture_attributes: [:location_id, :id, :image] )
  end
end
```

and my view

```
<section class="new-product">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row white_panel">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2 class="text-center">Add New Location</h2>
                <hr>
                <%= form_for([:admin, Location.new], html: { multipart: true, class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
                  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <%= f.label :county_name %><br>
                      <%= f.text_field :county_name, class: 'form-control' %><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">  
                      <%= f.label :description %><br>
                      <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control' %><br>
                    </div>
                  <p>Upload Picture</p>
                  <%= f.fields_for :picture, Picture.new do |image_upload| %> 
                    <%= image_upload.file_field :image, style: 'padding-bottom: 25px;' %>
                  <% end %>
                  <%= f.submit 'Go!', class: 'btn btn-gen np' %>
                <% end %> 
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>  
</section>
```

right now, I'm not getting any errors. The location is made just fine, but nothing is happening to the picture table. It's just returning nil.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong with this? I have seen some resources for how to do this, but it seems like it's normally with old versions.

If it helps anyone I'm using 
`rails 4.2.6` 
`ruby 2.2.2p95` 
`paperclip 4.3.6`

any help at all about how to handle these relationships would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out thanks to [this](http://www.railscook.com/recipes/multiple-files-upload-with-nested-resource-using-paperclip-in-rails/)

view

```
<%= form_for([:admin, Location.new], html: { multipart: true, class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :county_name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :county_name, class: 'form-control' %><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">  
      <%= f.label :description %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control' %><br>
    </div>
    <p>Upload Pictures</p>
      <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true, style: 'padding-bottom: 25px;' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Go!', class: 'btn btn-gen np' %>
 <% end %>
```

controller

```
class Admin::LocationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!

  def new
    @location = Location.new
    @location.pictures.build # I don't know if this is necessary or not
  end

  def create
    @location = Location.new(location_params)
    if @location.save
      # images 
      if params[:images]
        params[:images].each do |image|
          @location.pictures.create(image: image, imageable_id: @location.id)
        end
      end
      flash[:success] = 'Location created!'
      redirect_to admin_location_path(@location)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  ...
  private
  def location_params
    # took out the other attr's
    params.require(:location).permit(:county_name, :description)
  end
end
```

now I can do 
`Picture.find(1).image.url` or `@locations.pictures.first.image.url`
and everything works fine :)